# Can i create the web page using Qt?

Tags: qt, user-interface, web, html

Actually I'm planning to create a web site. 
Can i use Qt to design my UI and web related stuffs? I have used Qt for creating various UI design and bit new to web site creation.

Comment: I've seen QWebChannel integration announced, should allow to expose any Qt widget. I had no chance to try it, anyway seems too good to be true...

Comment: @CapelliC `QWebChannel` is for facilitating communication with web content in a Qt application, It has nothing to do with "designing a web page with Qt".

Answer (score 3):

Qt is for making software on desktop and mobile platforms. It's not intended for web. Although there is [QMLWeb](https://gitorious.org/qmlweb/pages/Home) which is a JavaScript library that is able to parse QML code and create a website out of it. But it's a small and primary project which is far from mature and is no longer actively developed. I doubt there is any other option for deploying Qt or QML contents for web.